# Should model be immutable or mutable in MVC architecture?

Tags: java, web, model-view-controller, model, backend

Should model be immutable or mutable in MVC architecture like Spring?
I think immutable has disadvantages like duplicating code and harder to create new objects

Answer (score 0):

Quoting Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller):

"The model is the central component of the pattern. It is the application's dynamic data structure, independent of the user interface.[6] It directly manages the data, logic and rules of the application."

In Java you can say "mutable" or "immutable" only about an object. And model is not a single object - it's a component, which contains a lot of objects. Most of these objects are mutable, but some are not (Strings as an example).